# Is there any testing on the analysis and design software?

Tags: testing, uml, analysis

Usually testing is done after implementation. Is it possible to test an analysis and design before write the code?

Particularly, how can the following analyses and designs be tested:

1. User Requirement
2. Use Case & Use Case Scenario
3. Sequence Diagram
4. Class Diagram
5. Physical Data Diagram
6. ER diagram
7. Design Interface
8. Pseudocode

Comment: You don't expect someone to answer that in a handful of paragraphs?

Comment: Usually testing is done after implementation. can we test our analysis and design before write the code?

Comment: I guess that's better placed on StackExchange.

Comment: what do you mean I look for is a Test Driven Development (TTD)?

Comment: Sort of. TDD will first create test cases and then develop the meat. Your question is too broad. Try asking on StackExchange. They intend to answer questions like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test the dynamics of UML (fUML), SysML, and UPDM models using the [Cameo Simulation Toolkit](http://www.nomagic.com/products/magicdraw-addons/cameo-simulation-toolkit.html). Here is the [brochure](http://www.nomagic.com/images/products/cameo-simulation-toolkit/Cameo-Simulation-Solution-Overview-2016.pdf), where you can learn more about it.

Comment: At what price range does this tools start? They require to make a call for an offer. So I assume some astronomical number.

Comment: You can start with an evaluation copy for free. With a good enough story, the evaluation period can be quite long. I don't know the cost offhand.

Answer (score 0):

we can do the testing on our anlysis and design with software metrics measurement. like:

Weighted methods per class (WMC), 
Depth of inheritance tree (DIT), 
Number of children (NOC), 
Coupling between object classes (CBO),
Response for a class (RFC),
Lack of cohesion in methods (LCOM)

Comment: Metrics are no testing, but for sure they can help to improve  models. So basically your question should have been: "How can we improved analysis and design before implementation phase?"

Comment: My question still same. I asked my lecturer he answered like that. Mybe if need to improve models we need to know the deficiencies in our model before. the deficiencies will be a testing.

Comment: I see that English is not you native language, but still testing and improving are two different things. You can do tests to improve a model or you can use metrics. But testing has another purpose per se. It is meant to validate things (fulfilled requirements, find bad code, etc.). In that respect, testing a model is only possible the costly way @JimL. is pointing out: by simulating it.